# C Inline Assembly Unordered?

Tags: c, function, debugging, assembly, inline-assembly

In C I have:

```
__asm__ (   
            "mov    $0x2,%rax;"
            "mov    $0x6000dd,%rdi;"
            "mov    $0x0,%rsi;"
            "syscall;"
        );
```

But when I comppile it in the assembly file I see:

```
# 12 "mine.cxx" 1
mov    $0x2,%rax;mov    $0x6000dd,%rdi;mov    $0x0,%rsi;syscall;
```

why they are in 1 line like this
How to separate them?

Comment: Why do you say "unordered"?  The instructions within it are in the same order you wrote, still separated by the `;` GAS statement-separator after C string-literal concatenation at compile-time.

Comment: But there's nothing stopping the compiler from reordering your whole Basic Asm statement with surrounding code (no `"memory"` clobber).  And it's also totally unsafe because you're modifying registers without telling the compiler about it, RAX, RDI, RSI, and implicitly RCX and R11.  (**It's basically never safe or a good idea to to use Basic Asm inside a function, other than `__attribute__((naked))`**.  https://stackoverflow.com/tags/inline-assembly/info)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `\n` to separate lines.

```
__asm__ (   
            "mov    $0x2,%rax;\n"
            "mov    $0x6000dd,%rdi;\n"
            "mov    $0x0,%rsi;\n"
            "syscall;\n"
        );
```

Comment: Thanks, how can I add tab before each command to alline it

Comment: By adding tab (`\t`) like `"mov    $0x2,%rax;\n\t"`.

Comment: Please don't copy unsafe inline asm into answers without commenting on the problems.  This needs clobbers on RAX, RDI, RSI, and RCX + R11.  And thus has to use GNU C Extended asm.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `\n` will be helpful for you.

```
__asm__ (   
            "mov    $0x2,%rax;\n"
            "mov    $0x6000dd,%rdi;\n"
            "mov    $0x0,%rsi;\n"
            "syscall;\n"
        );
```

Comment: This is the same answer MikeCAT posted 6 minutes ago.  As I said there, please don't copy unsafe inline asm into answers without commenting on the problems.  This needs clobbers on RAX, RDI, RSI, and RCX + R11.  And thus has to use GNU C Extended asm.